# Automator: Move specific file from folder

Tags: bash, macos, applescript, workflow, automator

I have an Automator Service, which create .sketch file from folder content. I need to move the file to a higher level in hierarchy (for example, default output path is `…/ExampleFolderName/MySketchFileContent/`, needed output path is `…/ExampleFolderName/`).

How I can do that? Thanks.

[There is the workflow screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzBHH.png).

Comment: > mv .sketch ../

Comment: @peyo This is the shell script? If so, I get an error "-: .sketch: command not found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This workflow creates the archive at `…/ExampleFolderName/` not `…/ExampleFolderName/MySketchFileContent/`, as it's presently doing.

[image]

Comment: @Roman Kornikow, Glad I could help! BTW. I set 'Services receives selected' to 'folders', because I figured in this use case you'd only be selecting a folder. If that assumption is wrong, obviously you can set it to 'files or folders'.

Comment: Yeah, this is fine!

Answer (score 2):

Solved by another way. I just rename sketch extension to zip and extract